# Is there a better way to say "Lesser of"?

Tags: word-choice

I'm wondering if there is a better way to write this:

> Lesser of actual physical damage or $1,500 per occurrence.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a sentence, since there is no verb.

Comment: This is a question for a lawyer who practices in a country where the laws and the courts are both in English. Not a grammarian.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about advice on legal wording.

Comment: @ Thomas according to Halliday and Matthiessen (2004:6), a sentence is any collection of words that lie between a capital letter and a full stop. Besides that, you don't appear to be answering anything other than your own [undecided] thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Better is going to get you opinions, but since this seems to be something designed for a legal-esque document it's probably acceptable.  Usually I see the sentence constructed as "... actual physical damage or $1,500, whichever is less, per occurrence" which flows more nicely in my opinion.

Comment: I would not say "whichever is lower" but "whichever is less".

Comment: @Amory, Yes, it is a legal-type document, so my options and space are limited. I was curious if there was a shorter/sweeter way of writing it without distorting the message.

Comment: Amor, could "whichever *be* lower" a correct alternative form? If so, what is the difference using *be* rather than *is*?

Comment: Thanks GEdgar.  No, be is not correct as "be" is the infinitive form.  Personally, though, I like GetzelR's version as well.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] the cost of the damage, not to exceed $1,500 per occurrence [...]

Answer (score 0):

There are actually three fundamental problems with the original phrase, additional to the item you have asked about:

> Lesser of actual physical damage or $1,500 per occurrence.

1. You are not comparing like with like: you cannot compare "physical damage" with a sum of money! What (I assume) you mean to refer to is the ***cost of repairing*** the actual physical damage.
2. The correct construction is not the "lesser of A *or* B": it should be "lesser of A *and* B".
3. "Occurrence" of what? If you are talking about damage to a vehicle, does "occurrence" refer to each separate area of damage on the vehicle even if all damage was caused by the same incident? Or does it mean "per hire period"? I am assuming it means "per incident", i.e. per each separate occasion on which damage was caused. But you need to think about that.

I would suggest something like:

> ... the lesser of the actual cost of repair and $1,500 per incident.

But equally, you could use wording similar to that suggested by @GetzelR, such as:

> ... the actual cost of repair, up to a maximum of $1,500 per incident.

But really, if you are writing a legal document, you should be consulting a lawyer. The cost of getting it wrong, could easily outweigh the cost of employing a lawyer.